# Get play back details

Tags: java, android, react-native, react-native-modules

I want to get the details of the current playing audio in Android device if it's possible in react native or native modules bridge using java if it is possible get the package name app from which app is playing the audio

I have trying through the AI but

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.